# Click Event for multiple Textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, text, textbox

So I need a way for when a person clicks on a textbox inan 8x8 grid of textboxes, the text in the textbox they have clicked on is changed to something. My grid is set up in a variable called `textboxes[,]` so if you type `textboxes[0,0]` you get the first box in the grid.  As of now, with my very limited knowledge, I have this.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {

                textboxes[i, j].Click += new EventHandler(textboxes_Click);

            }
        }
```

Then I can handle whenever one of the boxes is clicked. If you have a better way of doing this, I would love to hear it.I just dont know how to access the box that was clicked, mainly the text. Hope I have explained this well enough. Thanks for all the help!

-Lewis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is good. You only have to define some additional information to handle it in the event, as follows:

We can define a class to store the textbox position:

```
public class GridIndex
{
    //stores the position of a textbox
    public int ipos { get; set; }
    public int jpos { get; set; }
}
```

Your piece of code sightly modified:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
  {
    textboxes[i, j].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_Click);
    textboxes[i, j].Tag = new GridIndex() { ipos = i, jpos = j };
  }
```

And then your handler:

```
    private void textBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;

        if (textBox != null)
        {
            //Here your have the text of the clicked textbox
            string text = textBox.Text;
            //And here the X and Y position of the clicked textbox
            int ipos = (textBox.Tag as GridIndex).ipos;
            int jpos = (textBox.Tag as GridIndex).jpos;   
        }
    }
```

**Edit**: I did some changes to the code, please, review.

Answer (score 3):

Your EventHandler has an object called sender as parameter. You have to cast it to an TextBox, then you can get the text of the textbox.

Answer (score 2):

Your event handler has the signature:

```
void Handler(object sender, EventArgs args)
```

Where sender is a reference to the TextBox that was clicked. If you also need to know i * j at this point I'd created a class that derives from `TextBox` which has those numbers stored within it.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the text box values by writting the following code

TextBox txt= (TextBox)sender;
string text = txt.Text.ToString();
MessageBox.show(text);

Hope this will be help full for u